# Android: How to enable/disable option menu item on button click?

Tags: android, contextmenu, menuitem

I can easily do it when I am using `onCreateOptionsMenu` or `onOptionsItemSelected` methods.

But I have a button somewhere in screen, and on clicking that button, it should enable/disable context menu items.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

Anyway, [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) covers all the things.

#### Changing menu items at runtime

> Once the activity is created, the
>   `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method is called
>   only once, as described above. The
>   system keeps and re-uses the `Menu` you
>   define in this method until your
>   activity is destroyed. If you want to
>   change the Options Menu any time after
>   it's first created, you must override
>   the `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` method.
>   This passes you the Menu object as it
>   currently exists. This is useful if
>   you'd like to remove, add, disable, or
>   enable menu items depending on the
>   current state of your application.

E.g.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {
    if (isFinalized) {
        menu.getItem(1).setEnabled(false);
        // You can also use something like:
        // menu.findItem(R.id.example_foobar).setEnabled(false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

On Android 3.0 and higher, the options menu is considered to always be open when menu items are presented in the action bar. When an event occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to request that the system call `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: `setEnable()` does change what happens when you press this menu but doesn't change how it looks (what's wrong, Android developers?). So it is clearer to either disable *and* change the title, or preferably just make the `MenuItem` invisible.

Comment: Quick tip: return `false` to disable the menu completely.

Comment: Plus the API comment on onPrepareOptionsMenu  clearly states: Deriving classes should always (!) call through to the base class implementation. You forgot your super call there.

Comment: Documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu

Comment: How do you know the integer ID of MenuItem added at run-time? You can only add them by name.

Answer (score 73):

On all android versions, easiest way: use this to SHOW a menu action icon as disabled AND make it FUNCTION as disabled as well:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_my_item);

    if (myItemShouldBeEnabled) {
        item.setEnabled(true);
        item.getIcon().setAlpha(255);
    } else {
        // disabled
        item.setEnabled(false);
        item.getIcon().setAlpha(130);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why set alpha to 0 when you can set visibility to false?

Comment: I'm not setting alpha to 0, but to 130.

Comment: Why set alpha to 130 when you can set visibility to false? Invisible button is better UI than greyed out.

Comment: Depends on the context of the button. If the feature the button would normally serve is completely unusable in the current state, then yes the visibility should be invisible/gone. However if the feature the button would normally serve COULD be usable given whatever reasons (eg. If the user becomes a premium member, if the user signs in, if the user connects to internet, etc.) then it's nice to have it greyed out because then the it lets the user know there is some existing feature they don't have access to for some reason.

Comment: Setting icon to invisible is not better in nearly all use cases. In the case you have a group its better they stay in their positions and greyed out indicates to the user that there is an option that can be enabled in a certain program state. making thing invisible and invisible and probably causing layout changes is very silly. There is a reason most menus grey out items and not removed them depending on mode.

Comment: What if the menu item inside of the overflow icon, so it will show text only? How can we show to the user that the item is disabled?

Comment: then it greys out automatically when you set it disabled, I believe. Haven't tested

Comment: @RichieHH Relying solely on color is an accessibility issue though!

Comment: @maracuja-juice no one said any different. But you can disable a button without it becoming invisible. The fact its greyed out for someone with proper sight doesn't mean it loses its accessibility for someone without. Think. It's "meta data" marks it as unavailable. Never hide buttons unless there's a bigger picture. That is an accessibility issue.

Comment: How if menu not contain icon? You can't setAlpha().

Answer (score 44):

You could save the item as a variable when creating the option menu and then change its properties at will.

```
private MenuItem securedConnection;
private MenuItem insecuredConnection;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.connect_menu, menu);
    securedConnection = menu.getItem(0);
    insecuredConnection =  menu.getItem(1);
    return true;
}

public void foo(){
       securedConnection.setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: That is the correct response to any Android version. Validated response is only valid for API 11 > devices.

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't work. Did you mean `onPrepareOptionsMenu`?

Answer (score 7):

How to update the current menu in order to enable or disable the items when an AsyncTask is done.

In my use case I needed to disable my menu while my AsyncTask was loading data, then after loading all the data, I needed to enable all the menu again in order to let the user use it.

This prevented the app to let users click on menu items while data was loading.

First, I declare a state variable , if the variable is 0 the menu is shown, if that variable is 1 the menu is hidden.

```
private mMenuState = 1; //I initialize it on 1 since I need all elements to be hidden when my activity starts loading.
```

Then in my `onCreateOptionsMenu()` I check for this variable , if it's 1 I disable all my items, if not, I just show them all

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_galeria_pictos, menu);

        if(mMenuState==1){
            for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
                menu.getItem(i).setVisible(false);
            }
        }else{
             for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++) {
                menu.getItem(i).setVisible(true);
            }
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Now, when my Activity starts, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` will be called just once, and all my items will be gone because I set up the state for them at the start.

Then I create an AsyncTask Where I set that state variable to 0 in my `onPostExecute()`

**This step is very important!**

When you call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` it will relaunch `onCreateOptionsMenu();`

So, after setting up my state to 0, I just redraw all the menu but this time with my variable on 0 , that said, all the menu will be shown after all the asynchronous process is done, and then my user can use the menu.

```
 public class LoadMyGroups extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mMenuState = 1; //you can set here the state of the menu too if you dont want to initialize it at global declaration. 

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
           //Background work

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

            mMenuState=0; //We change the state and relaunch onCreateOptionsMenu
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); //Relaunch onCreateOptionsMenu

        }
    }
```

### Results

[image]

Answer (score 6):

simplify @Vikas version

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

    menu.findItem(R.id.example_foobar).setEnabled(isFinalized);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What I did was save a reference to the Menu at `onCreateOptionsMenu`.  This is similar to nir's answer except instead of saving each individual item, I saved the entire menu.

Declare a Menu `Menu toolbarMenu;`.

Then in `onCreateOptionsMenu`save the menu to your variable

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    toolbarMenu = menu;
    return true;
}
```

Now you can access your menu and all of its items anytime you want.
`toolbarMenu.getItem(0).setEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 3):

A more modern answer for an old question:

`MainActivity.kt`

```
private var myMenuIconEnabled by Delegates.observable(true) { _, old, new ->
    if (new != old) invalidateOptionsMenu()
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.my_button).setOnClickListener { myMenuIconEnabled = false }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_my_action).isEnabled = myMenuIconEnabled
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)
}
```

`menu_main_activity.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_my_action"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_my_icon_24dp"
    app:iconTint="@drawable/menu_item_icon_selector"
    android:title="My title"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

`menu_item_icon_selector.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:color="?enabledMenuIconColor" android:state_enabled="true" />
<item android:color="?disabledMenuIconColor" />
```

`attrs.xml`

```
<resources>   
    <attr name="enabledMenuIconColor" format="reference|color"/>
    <attr name="disabledMenuIconColor" format="reference|color"/>
</resources>
```

`styles.xml or themes.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="disabledMenuIconColor">@color/white_30_alpha</item>
    <item name="enabledMenuIconColor">@android:color/white</item>
```

Comment: Great approach that can be used without much boilerplate all around the app.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: @ExpensiveBelly not a problem per se, just public notice.

Answer (score 2):

**the best solution
when you are perform on navigation drawer**

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.setGroupVisible(0,false);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: This hides the whole menu and makes it impossible to open it again

Answer (score 2):

If visible menu

```
menu.findItem(R.id.id_name).setVisible(true);
```

If hide menu

```
menu.findItem(R.id.id_name).setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {

                case R.id.item_id:

                       //Your Code....

                        item.setEnabled(false);
                        break;
              }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
```

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    // getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the OP's question, a few words of explanation will help current and future users understand your response even better.

Answer (score -4):

Generally can change the properties of your views in runtime:

```
(Button) item = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idBut);
```

and then...

```
item.setVisibility(false)
```

but

if you want to modify de visibility of the options from the ContextMenu, on press your button, you can activate a flag, and then in onCreateContextMenu you can do something like this:

```
 @Override
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, 
                View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

                menu.setHeaderTitle(R.string.context_title);

                if (flagIsOn()) {
                    addMenuItem(menu, "Option available", true);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Option not available", 500).show();
                }

        }
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I must say you are getting wrong, I want menu item to be disabled, not Button.

Comment: my answer is completed. This code it works, I've used in my projects

Comment: Well thanks for work, but You should read question properly that I've already stated that I can change it in `onCreateContextMenu` method. But I want to access the context menu out side from this method.

Comment: `onCreateContextMenu` will be called only once, but I can click on button lots of time to enable/disable menu item.

Comment: Yes, but the context menu normally is done to be hidden. If you press your 'somewhere  button' and set the flag as I said, this context menu is not visible and the next time that you reload your context menu, this option will be invisible.
Another option is to do another kind of menu with the same appearance to handle the events with another methods.

Comment: I came out with solution. Please check my answer.