# android eclipse menu enabled/disabled

Tags: android, eclipse, menu

I create a menu in an activity with the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);

return true;

}
```

But so, I can open and close the menu any time.
I want that the menu can be opened if a boolean is true, 
if the boolean is false, the user should not be able
to open the menu...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440601/android-how-to-enable-disable-option-menu-item-on-button-click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can just add an ifstatement to the function:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    bool x = true;
    if(x){
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
       return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this before and it didn't worked, but now it's working so I made an other mistake before. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome don't forget to check the answere and make this question closed :)

Answer (score 1):

just put a if statement in your code

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
if(yourbooleanvariable)
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu1, menu);
return true;
}
```

If you want to  preserve the value of boolean vairable use sharedpreferences here is the link
 [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)