# How to hide options menu

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to hide the options menu when the Nav Drawer is opened.  How do I do this?  The `hide()` doesn't work and I tried a few variations already..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_write"
          android:title="Write"
          android:showAsAction="always"
            />

</menu>


public final class OptionsMenu{
    private Menu menu;

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(MenuInflater inflater, Menu menu) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sample, menu);
        this.menu = menu;
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    public void hide(){
        menu.findItem(R.id.menu_points).setVisible(false); //Doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to collapse the popup of the options menu if it is expanded, or just to disable the menu from being openable overall?

Comment: use `closeOptionsMenu()` to programmatically close menu options

Comment: i want to hide the entire options menu when the nav drawer is opened, and then show it when the nav drawer is closed

Comment: where you call hide() method? what is menu object? move `menu.findItem(R.id.menu_points).setVisible(false);` to `onCreateOptionsMenu` and test again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here [Android: How to enable/disable option menu item on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440601/android-how-to-enable-disable-option-menu-item-on-button-click)

```
onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
private boolean isDrawerOpened; // Global variable
```

implement `DrawerListener`...

```
drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.SimpleDrawerListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
        isDrawerOpened = true;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
        isDrawerOpened = false;
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
});
```

and validate state of `DrawerLayout` in `onCreateOptionsMenu`...

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    if (!isDrawerOpened) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sample, menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `closeOptionsMenu()`  for close option menu