# How avoid clicking the same item in drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I made a drawer for all activities ready by creating a BaseActivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private static final String SELECTED_ITEM_ID = "selected_id";
    public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public Toolbar mToolBar;
    public NavigationView mDrawer;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mdrawerToggle;

    private int mSelectedId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            mSelectedId = savedInstanceState.getInt(SELECTED_ITEM_ID);
        }
        Log.d("aoi", "save instance "+String.valueOf(mSelectedId));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
        Intent intent = null;
        if(mSelectedId != menuItem.getItemId()){
            mSelectedId = menuItem.getItemId();
            Log.d("aoi", "selected item "+String.valueOf(mSelectedId));

            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.agency_menu_item:
                    intent = new Intent(this, AgencyActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

     public void initDrawer(){
        mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);
        mDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_drawer);
        mDrawer.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_parent);
        mdrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                mDrawerLayout,
                mToolBar,
                R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mdrawerToggle);
        // indicator based on whether the drawerlayout is in open or closed
        mdrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(SELECTED_ITEM_ID, mSelectedId);
    }
}
```

and will be extended by my Activities

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

 public class AgencyActivity extends BaseActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agency);
        initDrawer();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_agency, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

But then my problem is on how to disable the item in the drawer if it's showing already the activity?
for example: I click the "agency" item on the drawer and when I'm already on that activity I won't be able to click it again, to avoid opening a new activity of `AgencyActivity`.

I tried using the `onSaveInstanceState` to save the value of item selected and compare it when I try to select it again, but no luck. I think it goes back to zero when the new activity is called via intent.

I'm Currently using **Android Design support library** for this one.

Answer (score 3):

Just disable the menu when clicking:

```
menu.getItem(menuItem.getItemId()).setEnabled(false);
```

Then enable it when necessary with `setEnabled(true);`.

Comment: Im sorry for this question, but where can I put it? inside onNavigationItemSelected? because when i tried it the "menu" in 

menu.getItem(menuItem.getItemId()).setEnabled(false);

is in red. sorry for that noob question

Comment: `getItem(int itemID)` receives the id, in this case you must put inside menu item id, you use getItem() in any part when you have access to a `menuItem` and get `.getItemId()`  for example... `onNavigationItemSelected`

Comment: am I going to make a new method for getItem(int itemID)?

Comment: nope! this method is in the menu, you just say here which menu position disable... check the api http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#getItem(int)

Comment: still cant figure out man. can you give me the snippet? because what I did is this: 

 @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.getItem(mSelectedId).setEnabled(false);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

but still doesnt disable the Item in the drawer

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5441329/3850595, since android 3.0 you must execute `invalidateOptionsMenu()` to force `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` being called... then you will be able to change menu options....

Comment: I made it work but Im not satisfied with the transition of opening a new activity. I'll switch on using a fragment. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer. Thanks BTW with all your help.