# How to disable items in menu after button is clicked?

Tags: android, button, menu

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private final int item_4 = 4;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPrepareOptionsMenu();
            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {


        MenuInflater mi = getMenuInflater();
        mi.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


        menu.add(Menu.NONE, item_4, Menu.NONE, "Show");

       menu.add(Menu.NONE, item_4, Menu.NONE, "Hide");


        menu.add("Reset");




        return true;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {




        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.item1:

                Toast.makeText(this, "You Pressed Settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;


            case R.id.item2:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You Pressed Create", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.item3:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You Pressed Delete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;


            case item_4:
                Toast.makeText(this, "You Pressed Hide", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem mii = menu.findItem(R.id.item2);
        mii.setEnabled(false);


        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```

In the above code I have created a menu item list for the app bar and I have created a button in my app and i want some of my items to be disabled after button click but I am not able to do so as I am not gettig how to call onPrepareOptionsMenu() on button click? Can anyone suggest a solution for how to disable the menu items after button click?

Answer (score 0):

I will show short example:

Only one note for this method: don’t forget to clear menu items (menu.clear();) on every method start.

Example:

```html
import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

/**

* Class which shows how to change dynamically options menu items

*/

public class Main extends Activity {

private Button clickBtn;

private boolean isChangedStat = false;

private static final int MENUITEM = Menu.FIRST;

@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

clickBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.click);

clickBtn.setText("Click me");

clickBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

if(isChangedStat) {

isChangedStat = false;

} else {

isChangedStat = true;

}

}

});

}

@Override

public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

menu.clear();

if(isChangedStat) {

menu.add(0, MENUITEM, 0, "True");

} else {

menu.add(0, MENUITEM, 0, "False");

}

return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reference from:
[Android: How to enable/disable option menu item on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440601/android-how-to-enable-disable-option-menu-item-on-button-click)

> Once the activity is created, the onCreateOptionsMenu() method is
>   called only once, as described above. The system keeps and re-uses the
>   Menu you define in this method until your activity is destroyed. If
>   you want to change the Options Menu any time after it's first created,
>   you must override the onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This passes you
>   the Menu object as it currently exists. This is useful if you'd like
>   to remove, add, disable, or enable menu items depending on the current
>   state of your application.

you could call the method invalidateOptionsMenu(); in your button's click listener. It will call onPrepareOptionsMenu() again, all your logic to disable could be written here.

Anyway, [documents](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu) covers all.